# How to create a database trigger with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, database-trigger, sqlcommand

I am trying to create a trigger with `SqlCommand` and I am getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'trigger'

When I copy the same query in SQL Server it is executing successfully.

Here is how the SQL command looks like.

```
command.CommandText = "CREATE TRIGGER tr_Korisnik" + korisnik.KorisnikID + "_FakturaStavka_ForInsert " +
                        "on Korisnik"+korisnik.KorisnikID+"_FakturaStavka " +
                        "FOR INSERT " +
                        "AS " +                            
                        "BEGIN " +
                        "DECLARE @ID int " +
                        "DECLARE @FakturaID int " +
                        "DECLARE @StavkaBr int " +
                        "SET @ID = (SELECT DokumentID from inserted) " +
                        "SET @FakturaID = (SELECT FakturaID from inserted) " +
                        "UPDATE Korisnik"+korisnik.KorisnikID+"_Fakturi SET BrStavki = BrStavki+1 WHERE DokumentID = @FakturaID " +
                        "SET @StavkaBr = (SELECT Korisnik"+korisnik.KorisnikID+"_Fakturi.BrStavki FROM Korisnik"+korisnik.KorisnikID+"_Fakturi WHERE DokumentID = @FakturaID) " +
                        "UPDATE Korisnik"+korisnik.KorisnikID+"_FakturaStavka SET StavkaBroj =  @StavkaBr WHERE DokumentID = @ID END";


command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, above that I have SQLCommands for `CREATE TABLE` and they work properly.

I tried `USE [databasename]` before `CREATE TRIGGER`, still nothing.
I removed the concatenations `+"korisnik.KorisnikID"` and made clean names, still can't execute it.

Comment: Triggers are meant for automatic execution, when a DML like Update, Insert, Delete is run. You cannot create or execute a trigger using ADO.Net APIs

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868704/why-am-i-unable-to-create-a-trigger-using-my-sqlcommand)

Comment: 1) This trigger is wrong because it assumes that INSERT statement/action will insert only one row (`SET @ID = (SELECT DokumentID from inserted)`). 2) Most of the time, creating a trigger is a one time job: they are not created at runtime. Instead they are created using SQL Server Manegement Studio. 3) Please explain the goal of this trigger.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version ? SELECT @@version ! I hope you don't have compact edition !

Comment: This seems like a design flaw. Triggers, like tables, should not be created or altered in runtime, but in design time.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

Which sort of confirms my suspicions: *you can't create a trigger this way.*

If you want to create a trigger in code, use a [CLR Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/938d9dz2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: CLR Trigger is still a class doing the same job a Create Trigger in Sql statements. ADO.Net APIs cannot execute the statements like Create Trigger

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure in your database to create a trigger then pass the correct parameters. Call the stored procedure with ado.net and pass params.

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned, a trigger should be created at design time.
Nevertheless, as follows it is possible with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery).

Use the [`EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement and the stored procedure [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC sp_executeSQL N'CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON myTable...'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```